# Getting difference of 1 day when date is sent from android application to php

Tags: java, php, android

I am developing the android application in which persons can enter leave application.
Here users select the date from the Android Calendar and from this selected Date Epoch value is sent to php page on converting the epoch readable date format i get a difference of 1 Day.

As on php page i calculate the to date for the leave using the number of leave and from date but here i m getting the wrong value as from date on the php differs from the selected date on the android application.

Kindly help..

Comment: May be its a time zone issue.

Comment: do in need to set timezone for epoch timestamp in php or java???

Comment: They get a default timezone upon creation. But it makes a difference between 0 and 1 day if there different timezones involved. Especially if you create a date, transfer the timestamp (as long int) and create another date from it.

Comment: I just checked in php and found that when i pass the unix timestamp from the java it is in Local Timezone that is of "Asia/Kolkata" but when it is passed to php it consider that timestamp as GMT Timezone..

Comment: Kolkata is GMT + 5.5 hours, so in the evening hours you may get an difference in the day of month.

Comment: When i changed the timezone to GMT in the tablet i was testing the date started to come properly..

Comment: Thanx Stefan for pointing out the issue..

Comment: Then I make a proper answer out of the comments :-)

Answer (score 0):

It turned out to be a timezone issue. The dates get a default timezone upon creation. But it makes a difference between 0 and 1 day if there different timezones involved. Especially if you create a date, transfer the timestamp (as long int) and create another date from it.

For more details see the comments to the question :-)